# Django class based views. Use same custom class for different url

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I would like to know if it would be possible to create only a custom class for my views in django that could be valid for different urls.

For example:

```
#urls.py 
url(r'^$', CustomClass.as_view(), name='index'),
url(r'^other_url/(?P<example>[-\w]+)$', CustomClass.as_view(), name='other')

#views.py
CustomClass(View):
    # for / url
    def first_method(self, request):
        pass
    # for other_url/
    def second_method(self, request, example):
        pass
```

I have readed the documentation about class based views, but in the example only talks about a single url...
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/intro/

So, I suppose I have to create a class for each url. But it would be possible use the same class with different methods for different url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create different classes for different urls. Although it is pretty redundant to have the same class in different urls, you could do:

```
url(r'^$', CustomClass.as_view(), name='index'),
url(r'^other_url/(?P<example>[-\w]+)$', CustomClass.as_view(), name='other')
```

exactly what you're doing. There are some cases where you have a generic class you want to use (either generic from the `generics` module/package, or generic in the OOP sense). Say, an example:

```
url(r'^$', CustomBaseClass.as_view(), name='index'),
url(r'^other_url/(?P<example>[-\w]+)$', CustomChildClass.as_view(), name='other')
```

Or even the same class with only different configuration (regarding generic classes (descending from `View`): accepted named parameters depend on how are they defined in your class):

```
url(r'^$', AGenericClass.as_view(my_model=AModel), name='index'),
url(r'^other_url/(?P<example>[-\w]+)$', AGenericClass.as_view(my_model=Other), name='other')
```

**Summary** You have no restriction at all when using generic views, or passing any kind of callable at all, when using `url`.

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to try your second or third example. Because In the first example I don't know how to call different methods for different url using the same class... May be with a parameter in as_view(method='first_method')

Comment: Generics are intended to be used as in the second example (by inheritance) or even the third one (although I wouldn't do it, but it is allowed).

Comment: Thank you for your advice! So, it is better an independent class for each url? I would like to learn best practices...

Comment: IMHO I would not use the 3rd, perhaps. I don't like importing the model classes in the urls.py. But, again, is just my taste.